# Launching Activity from Widget and catch ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, widget, toast, launch

I try to do a simple widget to launch an external App (ex: Twitter)
I want to use a `Toast` message if App not Found using `ActivityNotFoundException` but Toast don't work. This is my code inside `onUpdated`.

```
try {
    // Create an Intent to launch Twitter
    Intent intent3 = new Intent();

    ComponentName cn3 = new ComponentName("com.twitter.android",
        "com.twitter.android.MainActivity");
    intent3.setComponent(cn3);

    PendingIntent pending3 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
    intent3, 0);

    RemoteViews views3 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView3, pending3);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(currentWidgetId, views3);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Twitter not installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Are you running this code in background?

Comment: Te code is in the android.appwidget.provider in my MainActivity in onUpdate section

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Twitter not installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: The Toast code work, I try it in another code zone. I believe the problem is in the catch (ActivityNotFoundException)

Comment: Maybe is another exception, different from ActivityNotFoundException

Comment: Thanks. Some idea about what exception catch if the App (intent/activity) is not found?

Comment: You can change ActivityNotFoundException by Exception. If you want to known the exact exception check your logcat

Comment: I change to "Exception" but don't work. I can't find in the logcat the exact exception when i click the widget :(

Comment: Hi...I finally found checking my logcat what happen when i click the widget and i don't have any exception (Red). When I launch twitter activity Activity Manager line is green. I really do not understand why because the app is not installed. I suppose for this reason i'm unable to catch any exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static String WIDGET_CLICKED = "widget_clicked";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager  appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
            intent.setAction(WIDGET_CLICKED);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.example_widget_button, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        if (intent.getAction().equals(WIDGET_CLICKED)) {
            try {
                Intent twitterIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                twitterIntent.setClassName("com.twitter.android", "com.twitter.android.MainActivity");
                twitterIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(twitterIntent);
            } catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Twitter not installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code-only answers are discouraged, as they don't provide insight into how the problem was solved. Please include a description of how your code resolves the OP's problem :)

Comment: And please format code as code (I have done this for you ...); you had left some curly braces as normal text, disrupting the code block.